# Compilation Error - does not have the same signature as delegate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

> BC30408: Method 'Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As
>   System.EventArgs)' does not have the same signature as delegate
>   'Delegate Sub AuthenticateEventHandler(sender As Object, e As
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)'.

**Error occurs on this**

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser">
```

**Detailed info about error.**

> Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 8.0.50727.5420 for
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 2.0.50727.5420 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Login.aspx(43) : error BC30408: Method 'Protected
>   Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' does not
>   have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   AuthenticateEventHandler(sender As Object, e As
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)'.
>
> ```
>         AddHandler __ctrl.Authenticate, AddressOf Me.ValidateUser
>                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Login.aspx(43) : error BC30408: Method 'Protected
> ```
>
> Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' does not
>   have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   AuthenticateEventHandler(sender As Object, e As
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)'.
>
> ```
>         RemoveHandler __ctrl.Authenticate, AddressOf Me.ValidateUser
>                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Comment: some parameters on your declare function are wrong...

Comment: It is working fine when I test it in VS and in webhosting site.  But facing this error when I try to open it using localhost machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A clue lies *before* your error message:

> Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 8.0.50727.5420 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 2.0.50727.5420 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

That's an ancient (2005!) version of the VB compiler that presumably doesn't handle delegate variance. While you *could* change the signature of your method, you'd be better off making your local machine use a more up-to-date version of the VB compiler. My guess is that this is IIS doing the compilation for you, so you basically need to edit the IIS settings. (I'm not an ASP.NET expert so I can't tell you exactly where to do that, but hopefully that's enough to get you going.)

I'm surprised that's the only problem you're running into, to be honest - using that version of VB, you'd have no LINQ for example...

Comment: As per your advice I changed the .Net version in IIS which did the trick.  Thank you :)